# How to add lines segments to a google map

Tags: r, google-maps, maps, bokeh

How can I add lines segments between two points in a `gmap` using the `rbokeh` package.

For example, the code below draw the points but doesn't add the segments.

```
library(rbokeh)
pts <- data.frame(lat=c(40.73, 40.72), lng=-74)
gmap(lat = 40.73306, lng = -73.97351, zoom = 14, width = 680, height = 600) %>%
         ly_points(x=lng, y=lat, data = pts, col = "red")  %>%
         ly_segments(x0=-74, x1=-74, y0=40.72, y1=40.73, color="red", width=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`ly_lines()`](https://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/reference/ly_lines.html) to add lines to your plot.
Add `ly_lines(x=lng, y=lat, data=pts) %>%` befor your `ly_points`.

Comment: Do i take it that `ly_segments` don't work on maps? (I was hoping to use segments as I don't just want continuous paths like with `ly_lines` (unless i split the data / use a loop)

Comment: After reading your comment I think you are looking for [`ly_patch()`](https://hafen.github.io/rbokeh/reference/ly_patch.html). Please check it out. To check if it is what you are looking for you can also visit [the documentation for python](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/patch.html?highlight=patch#bokeh.models.glyphs.Patch). There is often an example to find.

Comment: Thanks for following up mosc. ly_patch looks a bit more like adding a polygon whereas I do actually want to add lines between the nodes, as in your answer. It is that by adding the data in to ly_lines then it creates fully conncted lines which is not really what i want. But I've managed a fudge given your answer. Thanks.